# Unable to process '/<diretorio>/test/foo.test.ts', please make sure that `outDir` in your tsconfig is neither `''` or `'.'`

Tags: typescript, jest

Estou configurando testes com **jest** em uma aplicação node com **fastify** e **typescript**, utilizando **ts-jest** e **@types/jest**.

Fiz a configuração inicial rodando o comando `npx ts-jest config:init` e criei no root do projeto uma pasta *test* com um arquivo *foo.test.ts* dentro.:

```js
// foo.test.ts

expect(1).toBe(1);
```

E por último adicionei o script de teste no meu *package.json*:

```js
...
"scripts" {
    ...
    "test": "jest"
}
...
```

Quando tento  rodar os testes aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Unable to process '/<diretorio>/test/foo.test.ts', please make sure that `outDir` in your tsconfig is neither `''` or `'.'`. You can also configure Jest config option `transformIgnorePatterns` to inform `ts-jest` to transform <dretorio>/foo.test.ts
```

Tentei alterar a configuração do outDir como está pedindo mas não resolveu o problema.
Meus arquivos *tsconfig.json*, *tsconfig.test.json* e *jest.config.js* estão da seguinte forma:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "compilerOptions": {
      "noEmitOnError": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true, 
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "outDir": "./build",
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "sourceMap": true,
   },
   "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
   "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

tsconfig.test.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
      "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

jest.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.test.json',
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Com muita pesquisa e depois de ler várias threads de issues no Github em vários repositórios relacionados ao **typescript**, **ts-jest** e **jest**, a única coisa que funcionou no meu projeto foi essa configuração no Jest:

```js
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      isolatedModules: true,
    },
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi esse problema com esse trecho de código:

```js
transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": [
      "ts-jest",
      {
        isolatedModules: true,
      },
    ],
 },
```

[Referencia da solução](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/isolatedModules/).